# iOS- use of undeclared type viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to switch from one controller to another. But the error shows undeclared type.

I have `import UIKit` on the controller but that also didn't work.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ParticularUserInfo", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AssignedScorerViewController") as! AssignedScorerViewController
viewController.USERID = USERID
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Which line are you getting `undeclared type` error ???

Comment: Do you have a view controller named "AssignedScorerViewController"? Check the spelling and perform a clean build folder.

Comment: @CedanMisquith I am getting error on the second line while instantiating controller.

Comment: Ok then follow @AsadAliChoudhry Answer..... Your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your `Storyboard` name is **"ParticularUserInfo"**? Probably it could be **"Main"**. Also verify that in your storyboard for that particular `ViewController` identifier is set as **"AssignedScorerViewController"**. 
to set Identifier, select your `ViewController` in storyboard and set `Storyboard ID`, according to my attached screenshot.

[image]